# VBA Code to highlight selected cells (it could be a contiguous range in a filtered column, so this is variable)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm banging my head against a wall regarding the following VBA code as I am a novice.
I want to be able to **highlight only selected cells**. This could be either by manually selecting non-contiguous cells with CRTL + Mouse left click or by selecting a contiguous range of cells with CTRL + Shift + Down/Up/Right/Left Arrow. All this regardless of whether there are filtered non-visible cells or not.

This code works fine but when it's only one cell that needs to be highlighted, it highlights the entire sheet:

```
Sub HighlightRangeYellow()

Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

Selection.Interior.Color = vbYellow

End Sub
```

See the attached image, first I manually selected a few cells and run the code, it highlighted them in yellow. However, if I only select one cell<

[image]

it highlights the entire sheet in yellow.

Thank you,

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: I can replicate that as long as there's at least one hidden row or column on the sheet with the selected cell. Add a test to check if `Selection.Cells.CountLarge = 1`

Comment: I cracked it and worked @TimWilliams. I think you meant this:
 Sub HighlightRangeYellow()

If Selection.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
ActiveCell.Select
Selection.Interior.Color = vbYellow

Else

Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Interior.Color = vbYellow

End If
  
  
End Sub

Comment: There's no need to do any selecting in your code `Sub HighlightRangeYellow() If Selection.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then Selection.Interior.Color = vbYellow Else Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.Color = vbYellow End If End Sub`

Comment: Or from the linked duplicate:  `Intersect(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)).Interior.Color = vbYellow`